# Linux and GT640M (w. Optimus)

Tags: linux, nvidia-graphics-card, optimus

Has anyone tried getting the `GT640M` (Optimus) to run on any linux distro? The last time I tried, bumblebee did not work and was stuck on my `HD4000` and my laptop's fan revved up to its max with overheating issues.

Comment: I tried it on Ubuntu 12.04 with Bumblebee and bumblebee-ui and it did not work. I have the 1GB GDDR5 model with an Intel Core i7 3615QM.

Comment: What laptop do you have?

Comment: Its the Samsung 'NP700Z5C-S04US'. http://www.samsung.com/us/computer/laptops/NP700Z5C-S04US

Comment: Make sure you look at [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage/+bug/1040557), use caution with UEFI and Ubuntu on that series laptop (it's a known, critical bug where you can brick your laptop).  Assuming it's installed already, don't worry, but I'd have a look at the bug report(s) anyways.  I thought I had seen a blog post regarding Optimus setup on that laptop, but my apologies - it was a Dell-specific process instead...

Comment: The last time I tried it was via Wubi when I was still on Windows 7. Now I am on Windows 8, and Wubi does not work. So I guess I better wait.